# MacPorts OpenSSL Force Link for Installing DotNet

Tags: .net, macos, openssl, homebrew, macports

I'm installing DotNet on my Macintosh using the MacPorts along with the [DotNet core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos) from Microsoft.  Their site says to install OpenSSL from HomeBrew:

```
brew update
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
```

I have OpenSSL installed via MacPorts:

```
ports install openssl
```

What does the "brew link --force openssl" do, and how can I implement that same thing using MacPorts?

Thanks!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to implement a command which you don't know what the function is into another package manager that it's not intended for? I doubt that's a good idea.

Comment: Since the question was asked in the context of the .NET Core, I don't think the OP necessarily wants to implement the "link" command into MacPorts, but rather wants to recreate whatever it is that that command does. Specifically, without the equivalent of that command, .NET Core finds the OS X version of OpenSSL (0.9.8something) but not the MacPorts version (1.0.2something) and crashes.

Comment: `brew link` creates symlinks for the files installed by the openssl Formula in `/usr/local`; Homebrew usually only installs the files in a folder below `/usr/local/Cellar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to this particular problem but not the more general one in [issue 173](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/173) of the .NET Core. In brief, you need to link the MacPorts versions of `libcrypto.dylib` and `libssl.dylib` to `/usr/local/lib`:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Instead, export `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib` to make the loader find the libraries in `/opt/local/lib`, or use `install_name_tool -change` on the dotnet binary that references the libraries in `/usr/local/lib` to change the paths to `/opt/local/lib`.

Comment: Hmm, at least `sudo install_name_tool -change libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet` (and ditto for libssl) didn't do the trick for me: dotnet still throws a `DllNotFoundException` for `System.Security.Cryptography.Native` like it did before.

Comment: There might be a different library referencing the libssl and libcrypto libs, or dotnet might actually try to open the libraries at runtime using dlopen. My knowedge of dotnet is unfortunately too limited to know which one of those (if any) are the case.

Comment: I tried using `install_name_tool` with the `System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib` but that didn't help either. I didn't try setting `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY` as that might not be set if I run something without a shell? I reverted to my original symlink solution.

Comment: You can add multiple paths to the fallback variable. I added `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:~/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib` to my .zshrc/.bashrc